# Matlab array of structure

Tags: matlab, matrix, structure

I created an array of structures

```
data(1).field = 5;
data(2).field = 3;
data(3).field = -4;
...
```

I would like to plot one of the fields by accessing something like:

```
data(:).field
```

I get the following error:

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 1000 results.

Is it possible to get the data without using a loop?

Comment: You're getting a comma-separated list. Put square brackets around your expression to turn it into an array: `[data.field]`

Comment: Thx, it works when I only use one field. I also have structure of structures, something like  data(:).field1.field2, any idea in that case?

Comment: Use a data structure more suitable for accessing numerical data vectors, like a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Too late ... I can't refactor all my code

Comment: Yeah, you picked the wrong way to store your data. Not much you can do now but write lots of loops to copy data over into an array that you can actually use in MATLAB.

Comment: `[[data.field1].field2]` works in Octave, but no guarantees on MATLAB. Or use `struct2cell` and `cellfun`, but that's still loops.

Answer (score 0):

try `getfield`

like this

```
getfield(S(:),field)
```

`getfield` reads nested fields, as in

```
S.f1.f2.f3
```

then the call is

```
getfield(S,f1,f2,f3)
```

complete MATLAB help file here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the data without using a loop?

Yes,there are several ways to avoid for loops to get data.

In order to avoid the for loop(which that can only be a level by level), this can be done through the square brackets "[]" or convert matlab struct arrays to other matlab built-in data types (such as `table`, `cell`, etc.), the general use of the function is [struct2table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2table.html), [struct2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html).

---

- use "[]"

Actually converts the comma expression to a scalar array. For a tutorial on how to use comma expressions see the discussion at the following link.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/discussions/tips/847976-tutorial-comma-separated-lists-and-how-to-use-them

- convert to other build-in data type

This actually converts the struct array into another data representation presentation, with the sub-field(sub-level, which is usually the result returned by the [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) function) still being a scalar struct.

---

When you know the fieldname of a level beforehand, you can get the data of the next level in any of the above two ways.

For example:

```matlab
data(1).level1_a.level2_a = 5;
data(2).level1_a.level2_a = 3;
data(3).level1_a.level2_a = -4;
data(4).level1_a.level2_a = 8;

data(1).level1_b.level2_b = 2;
data(2).level1_b.level2_b = 3;
data(3).level1_b.level2_b = 7;
data(4).level1_b.level2_b = 10;

% get struct data, avoid for loops
level1Names = fieldnames(data)
level2Names = fieldnames(data(1).(level1Names{1}))
tbl = struct2table(data) % The column name is the name of level1.

value1 = [tbl.level1_a.level2_a] % get the data
value2 = [tbl.level1_b.level2_b] % get the data

cel = struct2cell(data) % 2*1*4 cell array
```